# ParametricPlot shows nothing for NDSolve solutions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

I want to plot x'[t] as a function of x[t] (phase space) with PararametricPlot but mathematica shows nothing i dont understand what the problem is.this is my code:

```
k = 1;
m = 1;
w0 = Sqrt[k/m];
b = .1;
a0 = 0;
wd = 0;
ftotal[k_, x_, m_, b_, v_, a0_, wd_, t] := -k x - m b v + 
m a0 Cos[wd t];
s = First@
NDSolve[{ftotal[k, x[t], m, b, x'[t], a0, wd, t] == m x''[t], 
x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {x[t], t}, 
PlotRange -> All]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 20}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x[t], x'[t]}]
```

Comment: To make things clearer I would define `sol[t_] = x[t] /. s` and then plot `{sol[t], sol'[t]}`.

Comment: `y = D[x[t] /. s, t];  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y} /. s, {t, 0, 20}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
       sol = First@
        NDSolve[{ftotal[k, x[t], m, b, x'[t], a0, wd, t] == m x''[t], 
        x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 100}] 
      ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], x'[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 100}, 
       Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
       FrameLabel -> {Style["x[t]", 15], Style["x'[t]", 15]}, 
       FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, 15], 
      LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 15], ImageSize -> 500, 
        PlotRange -> All]
```